# Resources for finding concerts in Tokyo

Tags: online-resources, japan, tokyo, music, entertainment

My usual resource for finding concerts while travelling (last.fm) doesn't cut it for Japan. Are there any English resources that will help? My teenagers like J-pop so a local emphasis is required.

Comment: I was about to suggest [Songkick](http://www.songkick.com/) as it has a location search, but after some inspection of the results for Tokyo, J-pop artists seem to be conspicuously absent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I presume you’re looking for something in English.

The main English-language listings magazine in Tokyo is called Metropolis (メトロポリス). The concerts section includes some J-Pop:

http://metropolis.co.jp/listings/concerts/?concerts=1

Answer (score 4):

So far the best resource I have found and use extensively is - http://www.tokyogigguide.com/ . The advantages I have seen over other resources:

1. Frequently updated
2. You can search schedule by month, date etc
3. Has links to the venue website as well as the sites from where
   tickets can be bought
4. More comprehensive and accurate than other
   resources

Comment: Hello and welcome to Travel.SE. Please, add some information here, don't just leave a link for some random site in a Web.

Comment: I would also strongly recommend Tokyo Gig Guide - particularly the ability to filter by genre in the right-hand sidebar. Much better than Metropolis in my opinion.